# WSO2 EMM - MySQL configuration don't work

Tags: mysql, database, wso2, mdm

I'm trying to install wso2 EMM 1.0.1 on Debian. The server don't start with error : database not configured or has not started up. I followed the instructions from documentation. The database exists with the content and I change the master datasources.xml file like the example.

Overview of the beginning of the file :

```
<providers>
    <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
</providers>

<datasources>
<datasource>
        <name>BDD_EMM</name>
        <description>BDD MySQL pour EMM</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/emmdb</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMM_DB</url>
                <username>EMM</username>
                <password>xxxxxx</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please double check database name, user and password as same as you define inside datasources.xml.

Also check mysql jdbc driver inside repository/components/lib folder.

Comment: I checked DB name, user and password. No problem.
There is mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar in repository/components/lib.

Comment: there is also /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar. I tested connexion with simple java code. At first does not work, because CLASSPATH wasn't set. Now it work fine but not WSO2 EMM...

Comment: <datasource>
        <name>BDD_EMM</name>
         change this to <name>EMM_DB</name> and see